# Python Groupby & Counting first in Series, sorting by month

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe (this is an example, actual dataframe is a lot larger):

```py
data = [['345', 1, '2022_Jan'], ['678', 1, '2022_Jan'], ['123', 1, '2022_Feb'], ['123', 1, '2022_Feb'], ['345', 0, '2022_Mar'], ['678', 1, '2022_Mar'], ['901', 0, '2022_Mar'], ['678', 1, '2022_Mar']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Error Count', 'Year_Month'])
```

The question I want answered is :How many IDs have errors?

I want to get an output that groups by 'Year_Month' and counts 1 for each ID that occurs in each month. In other words, I want to count only 1 for each ID in a single month.

When I group by 'Year_Month' & 'ID': `df.groupby(['Year_Month', 'ID']).count()`

it will give me the following output (current output link below) with the total Error Count for each ID, but I only want to count each ID once. I also want the Year_Month to be ordered chronologically, not sure why it's not when my original dataframe is in order by month in the Year_Month column.

[My current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti2s6.png)

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNOoX.png)

Comment: Were you helped by either of the provided answers? If so, please accept one (and upvote if you feel like you've learned something)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these actually duplicate records? Are you sure you don't want to record that user `123` had two errors in February?

If so, drop duplicates first, then groupby and sum over `Error Count`. The `.count()` method doesn't do what you think it does:

```py
df.drop_duplicates(["ID", "Year_Month"]) \
  .groupby(["Year_Month", "ID"])["Error Count"] \
  .sum()
```

Output:

```py
In [3]: counts = df.drop_duplicates(["ID", "Year_Month"]) \
   ...:            .groupby(["Year_Month", "ID"])["Error Count"] \
   ...:            .sum()

In [4]: counts
Out[4]:
Year_Month  ID
2022_Feb    123    1
2022_Jan    345    1
            678    1
2022_Mar    345    0
            678    1
            901    0
Name: Error Count, dtype: int64
```

As far as sorting, you'd want to convert `"Year_Month"` to a datetime object, because right now they're just being sorted as strings:

```py
In [5]: "2022_Feb" < "2022_Jan"
Out[5]: True
```

Here's how you could do that:

```py
In [6]: counts.sort_index(level=0, key=lambda ym: pd.to_datetime(ym, format="%Y_%b"))
Out[6]:
Year_Month  ID
2022_Jan    345    1
            678    1
2022_Feb    123    1
2022_Mar    345    0
            678    1
            901    0
Name: Error Count, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```py
(df
    .groupby(['Year_Month', 'ID']) # group by the two columns
    .sum('Error Count')['Error Count'] # aggregate the sum over error count
    .apply(lambda x: int(bool(x)))) # convert to boolean and back to int
    .to_frame('Error Count') # add name back to applied column
)

                Error Count
Year_Month ID
2022_Feb   123            1
2022_Jan   345            1
           678            1
2022_Mar   345            0
           678            1
           901            0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do that

Converting the sum to a boolean with astype(bool) to return True or False, based on values being 0 or non-zero, and then to 0 or 1 with astype(int)

```
df.groupby(['Year_Month','ID'])['Error Count'].sum().astype(bool).astype(int)

Year_Month  ID 
2022_Feb    123    1
2022_Jan    345    1
            678    1
2022_Mar    345    0
            678    1
            901    0
Name: Error Count, dtype: int32
```

To sort, assign the outcome to a dataframe and then apply the ddejohn solution to sort

```
counts = df.groupby(['Year_Month','ID'])['Error Count'].sum().astype(bool).astype(int)

counts.sort_index(level=0, key=lambda ym: pd.to_datetime(ym, format="%Y_%b")) # ddejohn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71927886/3494754 answer above


Year_Month  ID 
2022_Jan    345    1
            678    1
2022_Feb    123    1
2022_Mar    345    0
            678    1
            901    0
Name: Error Count, dtype: int32
```